# How to resize the search bar so that the index doesn't overlap

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I've been browsing stack overflow and can't find a simple newbie-level explanation for this.  I have the following behaviour.  When the user clicks the search the index is removed and a cancel button appears next to the search bar.  When cancel is pressed, the cancel button is removed and the index reappears.

Does anyone know a simple way to reduce the width of the search bar (text field) by 20-30 pixels on the right.  This is the way the contacts app deals with this overlay.

Any help gratefully appreciated.  I've built the view in a xib file.

[image]

Comment: If you are American, it should be "Favorites", not "Favourites" :)

Comment: British not American :-)

Comment: Are you using `UISearchBar` directly? Try using `UISearchDisplayController` class - this is certainly clever at showing and hiding itself.

Comment: I managed to find a work around which in the end seems the best thing for the app by making the search bar permanently displayed outside of the table view.  Will bear your suggestion in mind though.  Thanks.